# Unzip saz files java

Tags: java

I was looking through java documentation and there doesn't seem to be a way to specifically unzip saz files, which are session archives created by the network proxy Fiddler. Anyone have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: I don't know what saz files are. But if you can unzip them, then they must be zip files, and you could unzip them just like any other zip file. Or did you mean "uncompress"?

Comment: Sax files are session archive files. They contain http requests and response. And I'm not sure if regular unzipping works. Maybe but I was hoping there was a saz file specific way.

Answer (score 2):

According [this](http://www.file-extensions.org/saz-file-extension) it is regular ZIP with specific extension for file name. Use [java.util.zip.ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile%28java.io.File%29).

About not having specific method for this extension - I think it kind of makes sense to not to have specific method for every possible extension.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

saz files are regular zip files

```
public static boolean unzipFiles(String srcDirectory, String srcFile, String destDirectory)
{
    try
    {
        //first make sure that all the arguments are valid and not null
        if(srcDirectory == null)
        {
            System.out.println(1);
            return false;
        }
        if(srcFile == null)
        {
            System.out.println(2);
            return false;
        }
        if(destDirectory == null)
        {
            System.out.println(3);
            return false;
        }
        if(srcDirectory.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(4);
            return false;
        }
        if(srcFile.equals(""))
        {   
            System.out.println(5);
            return false;
        }
        if(destDirectory.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(6);
            return false;
        }
        //now make sure that these directories exist
        File sourceDirectory = new File(srcDirectory);
        File sourceFile = new File(srcDirectory + File.separator + srcFile);
        File destinationDirectory = new File(destDirectory);

        if(!sourceDirectory.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(7);
            return false;
        }
        if(!sourceFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(sourceFile);
            return false;
        }
        if(!destinationDirectory.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(9);
            return false;
        }

        //now start with unzip process
        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

        ZipEntry entry = null;

        while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            String outputFilename = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();

            System.out.println("Extracting file: " + entry.getName());

            createDirIfNeeded(destDirectory, entry);

            int count;

            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            //write the file to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE);

            while((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
            {
                dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            //close the output streams
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
        }

        //we are done with all the files
        //close the zip file
        zis.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files), found by googling "saz files", says:

> SAZ files are simply specially formatted .ZIP files. If you rename a
>   .SAZ file to .ZIP, you can open it for viewing using standard ZIP
>   viewing tools

So they're just zip files with a different extension. Unzip them exactly like you would unzip a zip file.